# Set hyperparameters to a learner in mlr after parameter tuning

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

I'm building a classification task in R using the mlr package, to tune the hyperparameters I'm using a validation set, and one of these parameters is the percentage of variables used based on importance using feature selection (chi.square method)

```
lrn = makeFilterWrapper(learner = "classif.xgboost", fw.method = "chi.squared")
params <- makeParamSet(
     makeDiscreteParam("booster",values = c("gbtree","dart")),
     makeDiscreteParam("nrounds", values = 1000, tunable = F),
     makeDiscreteParam("eta", values = c(0.1,0.05,0.2)),
     makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 3L,upper = 10L),
     makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 10L),
     makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
     makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
     makeDiscreteParam("fw.perc", values = seq(0.2, 1, 0.05)))
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5)
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 1L)
res = tuneParams(lrn, task = valTask2016, resampling = rdesc, par.set = params, control = ctrl)
```

I'm not sure if I need to do 5-fold cross validation in here, but the variable `res` gives me all the parameters I need, including the `fw.perc` which will prune my variable selection in order of descending importance.

My question is, how can I use these parameters to again use resampling (this time using `Subsampling`) but this time on the training data? This is what I got:

```
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("Subsample", iters = 5, split = 0.8)
lrn = setHyperPars(makeLearner("classif.xgboost"), par.vals = res$x)
r = resample(lrn, trainTask2016, rdesc, measures = list(mmce, fpr, fnr, timetrain))
```

In this case, `valTask2016` is the classification task I used for validation of the parameters. I used `createDummyFeatures` to do one-hot encoding necessary for XGBoost.

And this is the error I got:

> Error in setHyperPars2.Learner(learner, insert(par.vals, args)) : 
>     classif.xgboost: Setting parameter fw.perc without available description object!
>   Did you mean one of these hyperparameters instead: booster eta alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason why you get this error is that the second learner is a "simple" xgboost learner and not an xgboost learner wrapped by a filter, like your first learner (learnermakeFilterWrapper returns a learner).

So, you have two options:

1. You define a new paramSet in your second training, where you "copy" only the part of the res$x that refers to xgboost, i.e. without fw.perc
2. You wrap your second xgboost learner by the same filter

I hope this makes sense.

**EDIT**: This worked for me for the second option using the titanic dataset:

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)
library(titanic)

sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(titanic_train), size = floor(.7*nrow(titanic_train)), replace = F)
train <- titanic_train[sample, ] %>% select(Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Fare, Survived) %>% mutate(Sex = ifelse(Sex == 'male', 0, 1))

lrn = makeFilterWrapper(learner = "classif.xgboost", fw.method = "chi.squared")

params <- makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("booster",values = c("gbtree","dart")),
  makeDiscreteParam("nrounds", values = 1000, tunable = F),
  makeDiscreteParam("eta", values = c(0.1,0.05,0.2)),
  makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 3L,upper = 10L),
  makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 10L),
  makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
  makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
  makeDiscreteParam("fw.perc", values = seq(0.2, 1, 0.05)))

classif.task <- mlr::makeClassifTask(data = train,
                                 target = "Survived",
                                 positive = "1")

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)

ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 2L)

res = tuneParams(lrn, task = classif.task, resampling = rdesc, par.set = params, control = ctrl)

##########################

test <- titanic_train[-sample,] %>% select(Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Fare, Survived) %>% mutate(Sex = ifelse(Sex == 'male', 0, 1))

lrn2 = setHyperPars(makeFilterWrapper(learner = "classif.xgboost", fw.method = "chi.squared"), par.vals = res$x)

classif.task2 <- mlr::makeClassifTask(data = test,
                                 target = "Survived",
                                 positive = "1")

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)
r = resample(learner = lrn2, task = classif.task2, resampling = rdesc, show.info = T, models = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with the Filter Wrapper, but it doesn't seem to get the correct fw.perc value:


`> lrn = makeFilterWrapper(learner = "classif.xgboost", fw.method = "chi.squared", par.vals = res$x)
> rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10)
> r = resample(learner = lrn, task = trainTask2016, resampling = rdesc, show.info = T, models = TRUE)`


I got this error:

Error in checkFilterArguments(perc, abs, threshold) : 
  At least one of 'perc', 'abs' or 'threshold' must be not NULL

Comment: Try to first wrap the learner with the FilterWrapper and afterwards call `setHyperPars(lrn, par.vals = res$)`. You can not set parameters for `"classif.xgboost"` in `makeFilterWrapper()`. But it looks like what you want to acchive can be easily done with `makeTuneWrapper()`. Check the tutorial on nested resampling: https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/tutorial/devel/nested_resampling.html